# Let $A=\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a rank of a sequence convergent. Then $A$ is relatively compact.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a rank of a sequence convergent. Then $A$ is relatively compact.

Is it true converse?

Comment: What does "being a rank of a sequence convergent" mean?

Comment: Well, if the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is convergent, then $A$ is bounded, which is enough to conclude it is relatively compact.

Comment: Is what true converse? are you asking if $A$ is relatively compact then it is the "rank of a convergent sequence"?  Also do you mean range instead of rank?